Javascript why import module which get async data doesn't trigger DOMContentLoaded and load event
Sorry not a native English speaker.
I have a async data which get from other module to import.
when I import, DOMContentLoaded and load event won't' be triggered. And when I comment out import, it work
// main.js
<head>
    <script type="module">
        import test from "/js/test.js";
        console.log(test); // has data

        // can only work when comment out import
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
        });

        // can only work when comment out import
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            console.log("load");
        });

        // work no matter import module or not
        $(document).ready(() => {
            console.log("ready"); 
        });
    </script>
</head>

// test.js
let test = await f();
async function f() {
    const r = await fetch("url", {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "key": "value"
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        return result;
    })
    return r;
}
console.log(test); // has data
export default test


Do you see any error in console?

DOMContentLoaded / load is fired before your imports are performed, due to top level await maybe

@RickyMo No... Just event isn't be triggered

event IS triggered, before you add a handler for it

Probably because when importing an async variable, you are making the module asynchronous. The browser can then load the entire page before firing your script.
This answer covers a similar problem.
